# Don't understand WooCommerce Paypal Standard Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm building a custom payment gateway for WooCommerce which has been... challenging, mostly because I'm not a PHP developer so I have been learning as I go.  I've started by dissecting the PayPal Standard Gateway which ships with WooCommerce.  That gateway has an included class for handling IPN callbacks and I'm having trouble understanding why their code is set up the following way:

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param bool   $sandbox Use sandbox or not.
 * @param string $receiver_email Email to receive IPN from.
 */
public function __construct( $sandbox = false, $receiver_email = '' ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_paypal', array( $this, 'check_response' ) );
    add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', array( $this, 'valid_response' ) );

    $this->receiver_email = $receiver_email;
    $this->sandbox        = $sandbox;
}

/**
 * Check for PayPal IPN Response.
 */
public function check_response() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST ) && $this->validate_ipn() ) { // WPCS: CSRF ok.
        $posted = wp_unslash( $_POST ); // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.

        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
        do_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', $posted );
        exit;
    }

    wp_die( 'PayPal IPN Request Failure', 'PayPal IPN', array( 'response' => 500 ) );
}

/**
 * There was a valid response.
 *
 * @param  array $posted Post data after wp_unslash.
 */
public function valid_response( $posted ) {
    $order = ! empty( $posted['custom'] ) ? $this->get_paypal_order( $posted['custom'] ) : false;

    if ( $order ) {

        // Lowercase returned variables.
        $posted['payment_status'] = strtolower( $posted['payment_status'] );

        WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( 'Found order #' . $order->get_id() );
        WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( 'Payment status: ' . $posted['payment_status'] );

        if ( method_exists( $this, 'payment_status_' . $posted['payment_status'] ) ) {
            call_user_func( array( $this, 'payment_status_' . $posted['payment_status'] ), $order, $posted );
        }
    }
}
```

The first `add_action` registers a hook with a WooCommerce action and I totally get that - it's a way to extend functionality in an external package.  However, the second `add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request'...)` seems to simply call `valid_response()` - which is a local function - inside the next function `check_response()`.  Why couldn't they just call `valid_response()` directly within `check_response()`?

Comment: _“Why couldn't they just call valid_response() directly within check_response()?”_ - because then you would not have the chance to overwrite `valid_response` with your own functionality (or append your own, after), without _completely_ substituting your own version of `check_response` as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense, that they were planning for extensibility.  But would there be other reasons?  Just because it seems to me that probably no one (except their own devs) would be messing around with the bundled Paypal gateway.  Not to mention, that function itself doesn't really do much except dispatch to other functions, yet that's the only action they defined.

Comment: One more question @CBroe - can you actually _overwrite_ `valid_response()` as they've written it?  I thought, with Action Hooks, you're not overwriting but rather submitting a function that will execute _in addition_ to `valid_response()`, no?  

Being able to overwrite it makes more sense to me, extensibility-wise.  But as is, it only lets you add more functionality to `check_response()`, after the order's already been validated and actions dispatched.  Just seems an unlikely target for extensibility.

Comment: You can also remove functions added to a hook by other plugins, using `remove_action`. So if you didn’t like their `valid_response` method, you could substitute your own this way. (In this case, where it’s not a function but a class method, you’d also need a reference to the specific class instance though.)